# Gerar valores aleatórios de uma distribuição no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Olá!

Estou tentando gerar valores aleatorios de uma distribuição (Gama, normal e etc) no python, porém estou com problemas para importar a biblioteca.
Estou usando a seguinte biblioteca "import scipy.special as sps", mas está dando erro... utilizando tanto o Python 2 quanto o Python 3.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Qual erro está sendo mostrado?

Comment: Esse erro:                                                                                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o padrão pelo terminal é o python 3, surge o problema que o numpy não tem suporte pra python 3. Então uma solução que tive é usar o python 2 e instalar os módulos: python2-numpy python2-scipy.

Assim da certo.

Answer (score 1):

Pessoalmente creio que a forma mais correta de importar a biblioteca seria:

```
from scipy import special
```

Pode ser vista uma pergunta semelhante [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819733/scipy-special-import-issue).
Importar a biblioteca como sugeres não me parece possível.

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro!

Comment: @user20273 de certeza que tens o módulo instalado?

Comment: @user20273 Se estás a usar ubuntu, na linha de comandos, experimenta o seguinte: sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy

Comment: Olá Rui! Eu uso o manjaro, cheguei a realizar a instalação do modulo e continua dando o mesmo erro!

Comment: @user20273 Nunca trabalhei com essa distribuição, mas experimenta o seguinte: sudo pacman -S python-numpy python-scipy

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa baixar o módulo para poder usá-lo.

Digite no terminal (ou cmd)

```
pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

Baixe o módulo numpy junto com o scipy que da certo!
Vá no terminal e cole ou digite a linha abaixo.

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy
```

Comment: Olá! Baixe o módulo numpy junto com o scipy  e mesmo assim continua dando o mesmo erro, tanto no python 2 quanto no python 3.  Acredito que o problema esteja na biblioteca que estou usando.